# Can I use jOOX to find the xPath of an attribute?

Tags: java, xml, xml-attribute, joox

jOOX can be used to find the xPath of an element using something like this:

```
Element element = (Element) someNode;
String xPath = $(element).xpath();
```

Can I do the same for an attribute?  I tried this:

```
Attr attr = (Attr) someAttributeNode;
String xPath = $(attr).xpath();
```

But it returns null.

**Edit**: I've managed to work around it by creating my own xPath from the node's xPath and the attribute's name, but it seems like I shouldn't have to do this.  Here's the complete work around:

```
Element element = (Element) someNode;
String elementXpath = $(element).xpath();
String attributeName = someAttributeNode.getNodeName();
String attributeXpath = elementXpath + "/@" + attributeName;  // <-- work around
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until someone gives me a better answer, I'll use my own work around:

I've managed to work around it by creating my own xPath from the node's xPath and the attribute's name, but it seems like I shouldn't have to do this.  Here's the complete work around:

```
Element element = (Element) someNode;
String elementXpath = $(element).xpath();
String attributeName = someAttributeNode.getNodeName();
String attributeXpath = elementXpath + "/@" + attributeName;  // <-- work around
```

Comment: creating your own xpath is better and also is optimised